# DND icon not changing on-screen, but is changing in DOM

Tags: jquery, jstree, jstree-dnd

I need to be able to drag a tree node to a div. I'm having problems getting the mouseicon to render correctly. It always displays as a X (jstree-er), even when the class in the DOM is changed to jstree-ok.

I have debugged and am certain that the DOM is being changed. It just isn't being rendered any differently.

Nb. the solution found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/BYppISuCFRE) doesn't work, hence commented out that approach (the data.helper.find returns nothing).

```
$(document).on('dnd_move.vakata', function (e, data) {
        var t = $(data.event.target);

        // Valid drop target?
        if (t[0].classList.contains("dropzone")) {
            $("#jstree-dnd i").removeClass('jstree-er').addClass('jstree-ok');
            //data.helper.find('.jstree-icon').removeClass('jstree-er').addClass('jstree-ok');
            console.log($("#jstree-dnd i"));
        }
        else {

            $("#jstree-dnd i").removeClass('jstree-ok').addClass('jstree-er');
            //data.helper.find('.jstree-icon').removeClass('jstree-ok').addClass('jstree-er');
            console.log($("#jstree-dnd i"));
        }

    })
```

Update: jsfiddle added. However, it works okay in a jsfiddle. Turns out that coincidentally trying an older JQuery here highlighted the issue... 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3k2on78/)

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle and post it here or you can update your post and add code snippet

Comment: The UI won't change if an element with `jstree-er` has a higher precedence in your/jstree-dnd css rules.  Without a working sample, it's impossible to tell if there's *another* element that has `jstree-er`.

Comment: JSFiddle added, unfortunately though - it works in the fiddle. More stumped than before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue is some incompatibility between JQuery 3.3.1 and JSTree 3.3.7

The above code works fine using JQuery 2.2.4